# What text editor is git using?

Tags: git

I am new to git.

When I enter `git commit` into command prompt, it changes to some kind of text editor in that same command prompt window. What is this text editor? Is it Vim? Emacs? I have downloaded neither of these.

I want to know what it's called so that I can look up how to use it. I was unable to even exit the editor after typing a message. A Google search suggested that in Vim I should press Esc then `:wq`. That worked, but it hardly seems discoverable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be default to your default text editor, and if not found, default to [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) (which is like a lightweight Vim. For more information, check out other site, like *[What is vi?](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)*)

If you want to change to your favorite editor, use

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

where you wanted to use [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) as the default as an example.

Comment: Where is this default defined, and for what scope? Is my default text editor the text editor Windows uses to open .txt files? Git definitely doesn't open Notepad.

Comment: git is more natively linux thing, so by default it means checking `$VISUAL` or `$EDITO` -> in windows term would be environment variable of this two value - which windows normally won't have hence default to vi.  I will suggest if you don't like vi, just change it using the git config provided in answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Git uses [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) as its editor while committing your changes.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository):

> The simplest way to commit is to type `git commit`:

```
$ git commit
```

> Doing so launches your editor of choice. (This is set by your shell’s `$EDITOR` environment variable – usually vim or emacs, although you can configure it with whatever you want using the `git config --global core.editor` command as you saw in [Getting Started](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/ch00/_getting_started)).

So it really depends on how your environment is set up. If `:wq` exited the editor, then it's [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) or [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29).

Comment: So is vi built into git?

Comment: That seems to be only part of the answer. Git seem to use environment variables as well to find an editor.

Comment: @Martin: Uh? That's what the quote is saying. *"This is set by your shell’s $EDITOR environment variable "*

Answer (score 3):

Git uses [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) by default nowadays. I have no idea when that started (too lazy to look). But yes, unlike [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) or [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), nano is slightly more discoverable though not very powerful.

You can tell Git which editor to use by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable. This variable is used by more than just Git. You can also set it specifically for Git alone as [Felix mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756448/what-text-editor-is-git-using/42756511#42756511).

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
git config --global core.editor sublime -nw
```

The `-n` command will open a new window, and `-w` will "wait" until the sublime editor window is closed to complete git command.

(`git config -l` will show you *all* of the git related configuration, if you're curious)